# How to edit my existing php function and add another check?

Tags: php, function, sql-server-2005

I'd like to add another option for premium accounts. At the moment you can class change your character every 2 days but I want to add another check to allow every 12 hours for premium users. They are determined from another table in `PREMIUM` there is their `strAccountID` If they are not premium there will be no rows in that table for their account.

That's my current PHP function which works for all users and allows them to do it every 2 days.

```
private function doProcessClassChangeFormD()
{
    $db = $this->database[GDB];
    $character = $this->site->SanitizeName($_POST['character']);
    $num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT bNation FROM ACCOUNT_CHAR WHERE strAccountID = ? AND ? IN(strCharID1, strCharID2, strCharID3)', $_SESSION['strAccountID'], $character);
    if ($num_rows == -1)
    {
        $db->GetError(__file__, __line__);
        $this->m_ccError = Template::GetLangVar('DB_ERROR');
        return false;
    }
    else if ($num_rows == 0)
    {
        $this->m_ccError = Template::GetLangVar('CC_INVALID_ACCOUNT');
        return false;
    }

    $row = $db->doRead();
    $nation = $row['bNation'];

    $num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT Class, Race, Strong, Sta, Dex, Intel, Cha, Points, TransferTime FROM USERDATA WHERE strUserId = ? AND (TransferTime < DATEADD(DAY,-2,GETDATE()) OR TransferTime IS NULL) and zone<>199 and authority<>255', $character);
    if ($num_rows == -1)
    {
        $db->GetError(__file__, __line__);
        $this->m_ccError = Template::GetLangVar('DB_ERROR');
        return false;
    }
    else if ($num_rows == 0)
    {
        $this->m_ccError = Template::GetLangVar('CC_RECENT_TRANSFER');
        return false;
    }

    $row = $db->doRead();

    $oldRace = $row['Race'];
    $oldClass = $row['Class'];
    $newRace = intval($_POST['race']);
    $newClass = intval($_POST['class']);

    $pCT = new ClassTransfer($nation, $oldClass, $oldRace, $newClass, $newRace);
    if (!($res = $pCT->canChangeClass()))
    {   
        $this->m_ccError = $pCT->GetError(__file__, __line__);
        return false;
    }

    $newClass = $res[0];
    $newRace = $res[1];

    $free = $row['Points'] + $row['Strong'] + $row['Sta'] + $row['Dex'] + $row['Intel'] + $row['Cha'];
    $newStats = $pCT->getStarterStats($newClass, $newRace);

    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
        $free -= $newStats[$i];

    if ($free > 255)
    {
        $_SESSION['bClassTransfer'] = true;
        $_SESSION['strUserId'] = $character;
        $_SESSION['bNewRace'] = $newRace;
        $_SESSION['bNewClass'] = $newClass;
        $_SESSION['bStrong'] = $newStats[KO_STR];
        $_SESSION['bStamina'] = $newStats[KO_STA];
        $_SESSION['bDexterity'] = $newStats[KO_DEX];
        $_SESSION['bIntelligence'] = $newStats[KO_INT];
        $_SESSION['bCharisma'] = $newStats[KO_CHA];
        $_SESSION['bAvailable'] = $free;

        $this->m_bSelectPoints = true;
        return false;
    }

    $newStats[5] = $free;
    return $this->doExecuteClassChangeD($character, $newClass, $newRace, $newStats);
}
```

http://pastebin.com/VK4Bi7FJ

I've tried several ways but no success. How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` with the `PREMIUM` table in your query that checks the transfer time. Then use a match in that table to conditionalize the time that you compare with.

```
$num_rows = $db->doQuery('
    SELECT Class, Race, Strong, Sta, Dex, Intel, Cha, Points, TransferTime
    FROM USERDATA u
    LEFT JOIN PREMIUM p ON p.strAccountID = u.strUserId
    WHERE strUserId = ?
      AND (TransferTime < IF(p.strAccountId IS NULL,
                             DATEADD(DAY,-2,GETDATE()),
                             DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 HOUR)))
           OR TransferTime IS NULL)
      AND zone<>199 and authority<>255', $character);
```

Comment: `strAccountID` and `strUserId` are different. In one account you could have 3 user ids. Premium is determined from account not characters. So, I believe I should edit it a bit. I can use something from the above query `$_SESSION['strAccountID']`

Comment: I did my best based on the information you supplied, I had to guess what the joining column was. It sounds like you need to make it a 3-way join. Anyway, the above shows the general idea, if you know what you're doing with SQL it shouldn't be hard to modify it to your actual schema.

Comment: Can I use `LEFT JOIN PREMIUM p ON p.strAccountID = ?` and add near `$character` second for `$_SESSION['strAccountID']` ?

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Comment: Last question can I use: `DATEADD(DAY,-2,GETDATE()), DATEADD(HOURS,-12,GETDATE())` instead of the `DATE_SUB` ?

Comment: I don't see why not. I'm just used to use DATE_SUB.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? I use MySQL, it doesn't have `GETDATE()`.

Comment: I am using MSSQL Server 2005. So, if Account ID is null in premium, it will take in place the first -2 days but if its not, it will take place -12 hours for example.

Comment: Unfortunately I did whats required and what you suggested but its triggered and it appears db error message from here: `if ($num_rows == -1)`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to go about it would be to do a query of the premium table:

SELECT the strAccountID from PREMIUM where strAccountID equals the current logged in user (stored in a session/cookie somewhere?)

From there just do a simple if statement. If the above select statement returns a row and the time has been greater than 12 hours, then yes let them change character.

Do the above around this bit here:

```
    $num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT Class, Race, Strong, Sta, Dex, Intel, Cha, Points,  TransferTime FROM USERDATA WHERE strUserId = ? AND (TransferTime < DATEADD(DAY,-2,GETDATE()) OR TransferTime IS NULL) and zone<>199 and authority<>255', $character);
```

Then all you would need to do is, if the person is premium, change the above statement to only 12 hours and not 2 days. If they aren't premium then leave it at 2 days.

Comment: I am a bit confused. Is it possible to upload the edited function on pastebin.com so I can have a look on how it should be looking ? I'll greatly appreciate it really. We can use from the first query in my function the `$_SESSION['strAccountID']`

Comment: You already have the basis of what you need to do. Create the SQL statement I wrote above and using the exact same code you use already (if num_rows > 0) ... do stuff if premium ... else continue doing what you're already doing.

Comment: I understand that and I appreciate it but I just dont want to mess it up that's why. I am not sure how to connect them both to make sure the rest will be executed.